# Facebook /profile path and pic_crop no longer working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using the profile/pic_crop option of the facebook graph api to request high resolution cropped profile images and detailed it's user here:
http://tactilefusion.com/tactile/high-resolution-cropped-facebook-profile-images/

However today I've noticed that this appears to have stopped working with the request returning 'Unknown path components: /profile'.

The facebook documentation still documents the profile path along with pic_crop and I can find no details of it being depreciated.

Any ideas?

Try the following link:
http://graph.facebook.com/tactilefusion/profile?fields=pic_crop
it returns

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /profile",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

it used to return

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "pic_crop": {
            "uri": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/t1/p320x320/10992_567316339955054_1439725697_n.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 320,
            "left": 0,
            "top": 0,
            "right": 1,
            "bottom": 1
         },
         "id": "447312341955455"
      }
   ]
}
```

If this has been depreciated does anyone know the new way to get a high res (better than the default 50x50) version of the profile picture cropped to a square as facebook does on it's profile pages?

Comment: Where do you find documentation about pic_crop at https://developers.facebook.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would http://graph.facebook.com/tactilefusion/picture?type=large or http://graph.facebook.com/tactilefusion/picture?width=1024&height=1024 work? You can read more about the /user/picture at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/picture .

Comment: You know what, it looks as that now takes the cropping into account. I tried using this API a year ago and it ignored the crop and would also return textures that were not square, the docs did say it would return a graphic as close to the specified resolution as possible which I guess included different aspects to the resolution too. I'll run with this for now and test over a wider range of users to see if all profiles are now compatible with this. Last time it appeared to work for the majority of users and returned unexpected images for some so I avoided it.